# Read-only mode stuck in gnome-terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, read-only

I have accidentally turned `Read-only` mode on in gnome-terminal, however due to a slight malfunction with my touchpad, right-clicking on launches another Terminal window so is there any other way of disabling `Read-only` mode? I have tried restarting gnome-terminal and my machine, but the setting is sticking.

**Information Update:**

There is a menu bar, but Read-only mode is unselected there and selecting and then unselecting it again makes no difference. The Terminal is still read-only...

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
Flavour: GNOME
GNOME Version: 3.18
```

**Package Information:**

```
gnome-terminal:
  Installed: 3.16.2-1ubuntu4
  Candidate: 3.16.2-1ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 3.16.2-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Can you access the window menu? The menu `Terminal` also has the checkable entry `Read-only`.

Comment: @ByteCommander: I have updated my question with more information.

Comment: Do you have the context menu key in your keyboard?

Comment: I use `3.14.2-0ubuntu3` on 15.04. For me, enabling RO from the context menu and disabling from the window menu works like a charm. --> File bug report?

Comment: @muru: Context menu in my keyboard?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-key-menu.html.en

Comment: Between right SUPER and right CTRL key, there is a MENU key. It should open a context menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I could not find the read-only settings in a config file or in gconf/dconf settings, I think the easiest method to undo it is through the menu.

You said toggling the state of the <kbd>Read-only</kbd> item in the <kbd>Terminal</kbd> window menu did not have any effect. I think this is a bug in your version of `gnome-terminal`, as it works for me in version `3.14.2-0ubuntu3` on 15.04. You may want to file a bug report for that one?

Now, the other menu where we can change the Read-only setting is the context-menu. You usually open it with a right-click, but you said you're unable to perform that with your broken touchpad (which makes me wonder how you managed to enable it then, but anyway).
Many keyboards also have a <kbd>Menu</kbd> key which should open a context menu in the current window. Yours seems not to have one though.

---

So we want to open a context menu with a right-click, but can't click ourselves. This sounds like a job for the famous **`xdotool`**!

Open another terminal emulator or anything which allows you to run commands. Move the mouse pointer above an open window of `gnome-terminal` and run the following command from the second terminal:

```
xdotool click 3
```

It will emulate a right-click on the current mouse pointer position. As this is on the `gnome-terminal` window, it will open a context menu there. You should now be able to unselect the <kbd>Read-only</kbd> option in that open context menu manually.

Comment: I would be tempted just to `reboot` :)